# How to remove the first word in an query

Tags: mysql

How can I remove the first word of an field in an MySQL query?
I have tried to work with SUBSTRING_INDEX but no result. The field is varchar and can contain both letters and numbers

Example:
`PWS 20110804 Pos. 04` should become `20110804 Pos. 04`

`PWS Pos. 04` should become `Pos. 04`

`PWS AA.0804 Pos. 04` should become `AA.0804 Pos. 04`

Comment: Please define what you mean by a "word" in a varchar field that contains letters and numbers.

Comment: This is probably better suited for whatever language you are using to query the database from

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) with [`LOCATE()`,](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) if you consider a "word" to be bound by a single space character.  `LOCATE()` will return the position of the first occurrence of its first argument.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, LOCATE(' ', column)+1);
```

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING('this has four words', LOCATE(' ' ,'this has four words')+1);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('this has four words', LOCATE(' ' ,'this has four words')+1) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| has four words                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Absolutely correct: for mySql, use "substring()" with "locate()".  I also agree with Pekka - depending on how complex your string processing is, it might be better to do it in a high-level language (like Java, Python or Perl) instead of directly in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

SUBSTRING(column, LOCATE(' ', column)+1) will fail with a one worded value and return the first (and only word).

This will strip the first word even if there is only one:

```
SUBSTRING(first_name, LOCATE(' ', CONCAT(first_name, ' '))+1)
```