# How do I keep everything after the 1st space in PHP pulling from SQL

Tags: php, replace

In my database (SQL) I have street addresses that have both the number and the street name. I would like to remove the number and only return the street name. How can I only grab everything after the first space using PHP?

For example:
44422 Lancero St    ->     Lancero St

Current Code:

```
<h5 id="street-address"><span class="street-weight"><?= $street ?></span></h5>
```

Comment: PHP solution. I will update the question.

Comment: If you are doing a sql query, do the trimming there: [How to remove the first word in an query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022828/how-to-remove-the-first-word-in-an-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `substr` and `strpos` to print everything after the 1st space

```
<?= substr($street, strpos($street, ' ')) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility:

```
<?= ltrim(strstr($street, ' ')) ?>
```

`strstr` will find the space and return it and everything after it, and then `ltrim` removes the space.

This will only work if there is a space, though. Maybe not a great idea on second thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to remove the leading street number from `$street`, you can just declare the digits and a space in [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)'s character mask.

```
$street='44422 Lancero St';
echo ltrim($street,'0123456789 ');
// output: Lancero St
```

This achieves your desired result given your input string with only one function call, but because address formats can very so much -- any simple attempts to remove the leading portion may run the risk of under/over trimming.

Consider this monkeywrench:  `Flat 18, Da Vinci House, 44 Saffron Hill` or `1313 1/2 Railroad Ave`

You will need to have high confidence of the structure of your inputs and/or keep an eye on things to make sure your data isn't mangled (with any of the methods on this page).